# C# Зависает при скачке файла

Tags: c#, download

Идет процесс примерно до 20% 40% и.т.д зависает и перекидывает на `client_DownloadFileCompleted` то есть как бы она завершена но файл не скачан полностью

**Как это исправить ?**

```
MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста ожидайте начинаем процесс скачивание клиента", "тест",
 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = null;
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://***/test.7z"), @"test.7z");


    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Клиент успешно скачался,Ожидайте идет процесс распаковки.", "тест", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Мало ли что может быть. Может, сервер отдаёт пол-файла. А может быть вы случайно скачиваете в один и тот же файл одновременно. Приведите минимальный воспроизводящий пример (без UI, разумеется).

Answer (score 0):

У Вас обработка написана таким образом, что не понятно, успешно ли завершилась async задача. Необходимо проанализировать свойства AsyncCompletedEventArgs.

```
private void DownloadCompleted(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //Тут обработка в случае сброса
    }
    else if (e.Error)
    {
        //Тут обработка в случае ошибки
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Клиент успешно скачался, Ожидайте идет процесс распаковки.", 
          "тест", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

}
```